# @ in p4 filename

Tags: scripting, escaping, perforce

I'd like to script p4 a little. Unfortunately, some of the filenames that we're tracking have "@" in the filename.

The filenames are in the form `a@b.xml`. If I try to do something like `p4 sync a\@b.xml` on a mac (or `p4 sync a@b.xml` on windows) it gives the error:

Invalid changelist/client/label/date '@b.xml'

Is there another way to escape it that perforce will recognize?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.  Use the ASCII expression of the character's hexadecimal value.

`p4 sync a%40b.xml`

See this article: [Limitations on characters in filenames and entities](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/o.fspecs.html#1041962).